# Finding percentage using group_by and summarise in R through dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, unique, summarize

I have some data about peoples' academic background. The user information can have duplicates so I use Unique_Elements to extract each entry only once.

```
demographics %>%
group_by(Academic_Level) %>%
summarise(Unique_Elements = n_distinct(userID))
```

The output looks something like:

```
Academic_Level     Unique_Elements
Freshman           22
Sophomore          76
Junior             87
Senior             56
NA                 10  # Non responding candidates
```

*The total value of N = 253.*

Now if I want to edit the above code to get percentages, what should I be doing?

I have seen the following two related posts, but they do not help me. Any advice on this would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

[Relative frequencies / proportions with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576515/relative-frequencies-proportions-with-dplyr)

[Finding percentage in a sub-group using group_by and summarise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549731/finding-percentage-in-a-sub-group-using-group-by-and-summarise)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative frequencies / proportions with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576515/relative-frequencies-proportions-with-dplyr)

Comment: Yes @avid_useR
Percentage of total unique candidates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
demographics %>%
  group_by(Academic_Level) %>%
  summarise(Unique_Elements = n_distinct(userID)) %>%
  mutate(perc = 100 * Unique_Elements/sum(Unique_Elements))
```