# Computing share of sub-group by month and year (tidyverse)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to the share of entity mentions online by month, as the share of total mentions at the monthly level, rather than by the total number of mentions in my dataset.

## Print data example

```
dput(directed_to_whom_monthly[1:4, ])
```

Output:

```
structure(list(directed_to_whom = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("MoE", 
"MoL", "Private employers"), class = "factor"), treatment_details = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("post", "pre"), class = "factor"), month_year = structure(c(2011.41666666667, 
2011.41666666667, 2011.5, 2012.5), class = "yearmon"), n = c(10L, 
10L, 8L, 30L), directed_to_whom_percentage = c(0.00279251605696733, 
0.00279251605696733, 0.00223401284557386, 0.00837754817090198
), year = c(2011, 2011, 2011, 2012), month = c(6, 6, 7, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To compute this, I have tried the following:

```
directed_to_whom_monthly %>%
    group_by(directed_to_whom) %>%   # group data entity mentions 
    group_by(month_year) %>% 
    add_count(treatment_details) %>%      # add count of treatment_implementation
    unique() %>%            # remove duplicates
    ungroup() %>%           # remove grouping
    mutate(directed_to_whom_percentage = n/sum(n)) %>%  # ...calculating percentage
```

But this essentially divides the number of mentions of entity X, by all all mentions in the dataset.

I have also tried a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549731/finding-percentage-in-a-sub-group-using-group-by-and-summarise), as follows, the code works well but it's not computing mentions by the total mentions per month.

```
test <-directed_to_whom_monthly %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% mutate(per= prop.table(n) * 100)
```

```
dput(test[1:4, ])
```

Output:

```
structure(list(directed_to_whom = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("MoE", 
"MoL", "Private employers"), class = "factor"), treatment_details = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("post", "pre"), class = "factor"), month_year = structure(c(2011.41666666667, 
2011.41666666667, 2011.5, 2012.5), class = "yearmon"), n = c(10L, 
10L, 8L, 30L), directed_to_whom_percentage = c(0.00279251605696733, 
0.00279251605696733, 0.00223401284557386, 0.00837754817090198
), year = c(2011, 2011, 2011, 2012), month = c(6, 6, 7, 7), per = c(2.49376558603491, 
2.49376558603491, 8, 30)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), groups = structure(list(
    month = c(6, 7), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to calculate counts for direct to who by month, and then the total count for all entries for that month  and then calculate the percentage based on that

```
directed_to_whom_monthly %>%
  group_by(directed_to_whom, month_year) %>%   
  mutate(direct_month_count=n()) %>% #count of directed to whom by month
  group_by(month_year) %>% 
  mutate(month_year_count=n())  %>% ###total count per month

  mutate(directed_to_whom_percentage = direct_month_count/month_year_count*100) #percentage
```